# how to write a scope containing an OR for greaterThan & LessThan - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

How do i write the scope for an event with an end date that is less than current date or equal to && greater than current date?

i tried the below but it does not seem to work:

event.rb

```
scope :events_with_endTime_greaterOrLess_than_currentDate, -> {where(['end_date > ? OR end_date < ?', Date.current])}
```

schema

```
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "start_date"
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "address"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "approve"
    t.boolean  "close"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_events_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

trying to display events with enddate less of greater than currentDate [but not equal to current date]

Comment: is this all events? can you give example table and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

As `end_date` is a datetime, the database comparison will be applied at that level of precision -- so your current code is only avoiding entries set for exactly midnight.

To avoid this, you can use `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` methods to get more appropriate times for your query:

```
scope :events_not_today, -> {
  where('end_date > ? OR end_date < ?', Date.current.end_of_day, Date.current.beginning_of_day)
}
```

Or, for a shorter spelling:

```
scope :events_not_today, -> { where.not(end_date: Date.current.all_day) }
```